# Find a conformal map from $\operatorname{ann}(0;0,1)$ onto $B(0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

It's from the exercises after Riemann mapping theorem,and we're required to find an analytic function on $\operatorname{ann}(0;0,1)$ onto $B(0,1)$,such that $f'$ would never vanish.

Since $\operatorname{ann}(0;0,1)$ is not simply connected there's no one-one analytic mapping.My rough idea is to find a function maps $\operatorname{ann}(0;0,1)$ to some vertical strip like $\{z:-1<\operatorname{Im}(z)<1\}$, then by exponential function $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}z}$, we get the half plane $\{z:\operatorname{Re}(z)>0\}$, then by Möbius mapping $\phi(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$, we get the unit disc $B(0,1)$. However,the main trouble is to map $\operatorname{ann}(0;0,1)$ to a vertical strip, if remove the interval $(0,1)$ from $\operatorname{ann}(0;0,1)$, then by logarithm function, we get a half strip, there's some silver lining to solve it.

Comment: Do you men "to" or "onto"?

Comment: onto.Otherwise it's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Such a function doesn't exist. If $f'$ is required not to vanish, then $f$ is unramified and this would mean that $f$ is a covering map. But then the fundamental group of the annulus would inject into the fundamental group of the unit disk, a contradiction.

Comment: Can you explain why it should be a covering map? A priori it is just a local diffeomorphism?

Comment: Sure. If the derivative doesn't vanish at a point $x$, then by the inverse function theorem $f$ is invertible in a neighborhood of $f(x)$, and the inverse is holomorphic. This means in particular that $f$ is a homeomorphism in a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: I'm not sure about the tools of Riemann surface you used here,but I found some discussion on the net on this problem,and they seem to be positive on the existence.But I didn't follow all the details.For your reference:http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=complex;action=display;num=1234362106

Comment: First of all, let me get notation straight. I assume that $\mbox{ann(0;0,1)}$ is just the unit disk with the origin removed? And $B(0,1)$ is the unit disk? If this is true, then at least the first solution I checked on the webpage you gave is wrong. You don't have to see my answer as a Riemann surface answer, the conditions on $f$ just mean that $f$ is surjective and locally 1-1, and we can see it as a covering space.

Comment: I hope I'm not missing something!